# Change fonts in Qt application on Windows10

Tags: qt, windows-10, mendeley

I installed qt5 application (Mendeley Desktop) from [here](https://www.mendeley.com/download-mendeley-desktop/) by using the instraller on windows10, and I don't like the default font; MS Gothic.

Is there some ways to change fonts in a qt5 application which I didn't build from source code?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they bundled the font into the application binary (via QRC), I'm afraid you can't.
Otherwise, you can check in the application installation folders if by any chance the font is loaded at runtime. In that case you just need to replace it (by keeping the original name) with your preferred one.

Same thing if they use the system font, but that would compromise all the other apps using MS Gothic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll check the installation directory. I appreciate your help!